# Strange data type conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var dropOffPlace_missing = $('#sidebar .journey h1').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})[1];

console.log(dropOffPlace_missing)
console.log(typeof dropOffPlace_missing)
console.log(JSON.stringify(dropOffPlace_missing))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zqvznu7n/

it's an object but when I'm seeing an empty {}, but it's actually has something in the first console? I'm totally confused.

Comment: @Guedes I want to get "Alor Setar"

Comment: That object is basically HTMLELEMENT (Text-node) to represent any text inside any HTML element.

Comment: since returning `this.nodetype===3` implies `return true` **if this node contains text directly underneath it**.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal so you have solution for this?

Comment: What is it that you need an explanation for this phenomenon or some specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `dropOffPlace_missing` is actually a text node.
The thing getting displayed in the console is representation of text node.

Try

```
JSON.stringify(dropOffPlace_missing.textContent)
```

it will print "Alor Setar "

Comment: how come when I print my object it doesn't show anything but an empty `{}`?

Comment: Don't really know the reason behind the behavior, but all Nodes except the Document Node returns `{}` when you stringify them.